# .then not working with axios.put

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have this code:

```
axios.put(`http://localhost:3000/api/put/change/${this.$parent.tableName}`, this.changes)
    .then((r) => {
      console.log(r.status)
      console.log('In then 2')
      this.changeDone = true
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
      this.callFail()
    })
    .finally(() => {
      console.log('test')
    })
```

I am trying to use `.then` but its not triggering. I deliberately make an error to test the `.catch` ... It works.

Is this write correctly because Im not sure that you can wright with `axios.put` like this

Comment: You say catch works, so what error message do you get?

Comment: I make a deliberate error to see if gets trigged

Comment: What does `console.log(error)` return. And if there is no error is `.finally` reached?

Comment: What i do to trigger the error is intentionally make the query have no sense . I will come back soon with what is outputted error. If there is no error the `.finally` is never reached.

Comment: this is the error: Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js?16d0:16)
    at settle (settle.js?db52:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?ec6c:77)

Comment: @ZakMicallef you found any solution to this? I am facing exactly same issue

Comment: I did but I forgot how I solved it. I think I manage by using anther format.